# Packaging a VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have written a simple VBScript that helps cancer patients manage their drug dosage (specifically *Capecitabine* - look it up if you don't believe me).

Many of these patients are 'older generation' and they are not very computer savvy, beyond being able to use a PC for Facebook and email. I was wondering if there is a relatively straightforward way that I could package up my VBScript (in, say, an exe or an msi or a batch file) so that the recipient could simply double-click it and that would be it - the VBScript would get installed and auto-run each day for them.

Comment: I just looked up vbs2exe  Note that softpedia is a good site https://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Coding-languages-Compilers/Vbs2Exe-English-Edition.shtml

Answer (score 1):

You can use a VBScript to executable converter like [VbsEdit](https://www.vbsedit.com/faq/convertexe.asp).  I have used this in the past and it worked without issues.  However, that was probably a decade ago, I dont know how well it works now.  Since they are still selling it, I would assume it is still viable.

However, it might be time to switch away from VBScript.  Microsoft is slowly phasing it out.  They are [disabling](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2019/08/02/update-disabling-vbscript-internet-explorer-windows-7-8/) it by default in Internet Explorer soon.  I doubt they will phasing it out as an interpreted language in the command shell, as *many* people and companies still rely on it for scripting.  Still, [PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/overview?view=powershell-6) is without a doubt the future.  Perhaps you should consider converting your script to PowerShell, or even a [.NET](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/express/) language like [Visual Basic](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/getting-started/).

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google reveals that 'Inno Setup' *may* be suitable for you (I've never used it, so I can't be of much help).